# Working with // urls locally

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to add [Reddit buttons](http://www.reddit.com/buttons/) to my site. This is the suggested code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.reddit.com/static/button/button1.js"></script>
```

Annoyingly, the `//` converts to `file://` when working locally. I have manually added `https:` to the `src` tag above, but the JavaScript file itself creates an `iframe` with `//`, which also converts to `file://`.

For local development, is there a way to force Chrome to use `https:` instead of `file:` in urls?

Comment: `Annoyingly, the // converts to file:// when working locally.` Because implicitly (as it's not in the question) that's the protocol you are using for your local development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do local development on a local webserver (there are many free HTTP server packages available). Web development works poorly without one.

This will also enable URLs relative to the root of the site, deal with many security restrictions when writing JavaScript to access other files and allow you to develop server side code.